# reason why this code has a runtime error vs compilation error

Tags: java, templates, generics, compilation, runtime

so I have this code right here : wanted to know why the 2 examples below gives a runtime error and compilation error

```
public abstract class Person<Mate> {
  public String name;
  public abstract Person<?> mate(Mate m);

  public static class Male extends Person<Person<?>.Female> {
    public Person<?> mate(Person<?>.Female m) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public class Female extends Person<Male> {
    public Person<?> mate(Male m) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone tell me why this code example gives a runtime error

```
Person p = new Male();
p.mate(p);
```

while this one gives a compilation error

```
Person p<Female> = new Male();
p.mate(p); // Argument is of incorrect type.
```

Comment: Please add the **complete** compilation error message / runtime error sessage + stacktrace to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because:

```
Person p = new Male();
```

is an example of using [Raw Types](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224).

Using any raw types causes the JVM to do very strange things. Don't use them.

Comment: Also using raw types will produce rawtypes warnings.  Heed the warnings.